# Accessing fields of an object that is a field in an object C#

Tags: c#

I've been working to modernize workbooks at the company I work for. I have created an object That contains information that I need to pull from a worksheet.

```
class Class1
{
    public class ItemData
    {
        public string Address;
        public dynamic Value;
    }
    public class SheetData
    {
        public ItemData Item1 = new ItemData();
        public ItemData Item2 = new ItemData();
        public ItemData Item3 = new ItemData();
    }

    public Class1
    {
        SheetData sheetData = new SheetData();
        //More stuff done
    }
}
```

I want to cycle through all of the Items in the SheetData class to get the Address field from them.

I have tried to cycle through accessing the members using:

```
foreach(var member in sheetData.GetType().GetMembers())
```

but I've only been able to access the names of the members in the SheetData class and not the Address field from those members. I want to be able to access that field in the loop similarly to if I used:

```
sheetData.Item1.Address
```

Does anyone know the proper method for doing this or is there a better way to approach this problem?

Comment: Do you really only have 3 instances of `ItemData` per `SheetData`?

Comment: @JoshuaRobinson no I have many more; this is just an example

Comment: Any reason you're not using a [`List<ItemData>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=netframework-4.8) in `SheetData` then? Instead of having a bunch of separate instances? Then you loop through the list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SheetData should be made up of a list of ItemData

```
class Class1
{
    public class ItemData
    {
        public string Address;
        public dynamic Value;
    }
    public class SheetData
    {
        public List<ItemData> Items = new List<ItemData>();
        Items.Add(new ItemData());
        Items.Add(new ItemData());
        Items.Add(new ItemData());

    }

    public Class1
    {
        SheetData sheetData = new SheetData();
        //More stuff done
    }
}
```

Then you can use a foreach loop to access each ItemData inside the list

```
foreach (var item in sheetData.Items)
```

Comment: I'm a little embarrassed but I think I was just trying to over complicating the solution. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep your current class structure, you might have to run a second foreach loop in order to get the memebers of the ItemData class.

Right now you are only iterating through the members of your SheetData class, so you have to run these members through a second loop in order to reference the ItemData class directly.